# Irreducible $G$-representations with unital algebra structure

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, jordan-algebras

Let us work over $\mathbb C$. Suppose that $G$ is a semisimple algebraic group and let $H \subset G$ be a maximal torus. Consider a dominant weight $\omega$, then one can associate a unique irreducible $G$-representation $V(\omega)$.

Consider the following example. Let $G=\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb C)$ and let $W=\mathbb C^3$ be the standard $G$-representation. We define
$$
V=\mathrm{Sym}^2W,
$$
it is a $6$-dimensional irreducible representation for $G$. Moreover, we can also see $V$ as the space of symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices. In particular, it inherits the structure of unital <s>associative</s> algebra using the matrix product. This is an example of Jordan algebra.
On the other hand, if we define
$$
\tilde V=W \otimes W^\vee,
$$
it contains an irreducible $G$-representation that corresponds to the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$.

In fact, these are all examples of $G$-representations that have also an algebra structure.
My question is: given a group $G$ and a dominant weight $\omega$, can we know when $V(\omega)$ has a unital algebra structure?

Comment: *Any* algebra $V$ can be viewed as a map (the multiplication) $\mu: V \otimes V \to V$. If we don't require associativity OR any relation to $G$, then of course we can define an algebra structure on every irrep $V$ of $G$. Of course you do want some relation to $G$, I expect you want $\mu$ to be a $G$-map? Then the first step is to find out (using Weyl character formula or such) for which $V$ we have that $V$ appears as a summand in the decomposition of $V \otimes V$ into irreps. This is already a restriction.

Comment: The second issue of the resulting algebra being unital or not is trickier (that is why my two comments are comments rather than answers) but I am also not sure if we agree on what that word means. I thought it means there must be an element $e \in V$ such that $ex = xe = x$ for all $x \in V$. But this doesn't hold in the case of Lie algebras, which seems to be one of your examples

Comment: @Vincent: Yes, I want that $\mu$ is $G$-equivariant. I correct the misprint: I want the algebra to be unital in the sense that you wrote

Comment: For symmetric matrices the product is not an operation (the product of two symmetric matrices is not always symmetric). You need the symmetrized product $AB+BA$, which is not associative (but indeed Jordan).

Comment: @YCor: absolutely yes! We need the symmetrize product

Comment: To make it explicit, bilinear binary laws on the product correspond $G$-equivariantly to $V\otimes V\otimes V^*$, and one should in general be able to determine the $G$-invariants in this space, which correspond to invariant laws (e.g., compute a basis). If one assumes commutative, it corresponds to $S^2V\otimes V^*$ which is also a "linear" problem. However, associative, Jordan, Lie, etc, are not linear conditions (on the law) so can be more subtle to figure out, it the space of invariant laws is large. Of course for a unit $V^G$ must be nonzero, and maybe one wants to fix it beforehand.

Comment: To make the Jordan algebra unital you should use $(AB+BA)/2$.  Notice the G action is not by homomorphisms so I guess the answer of @JohannesHahn is assuming more than you are

Comment: Correct, the operation on $Sym^2$ is $A.X = AXA^T$, not $A.X = AXA^{-1}$ like in the case of $W\otimes W^\ast$. The latter does commute with the Jordan algebra structure, the former does not.

Answer (score 4):

The unit poses a problem here. If you require the multiplication map $\cdot: V\otimes V\to V$ to be $G$-equivariant, then this means $gv\cdot gw = g(v\cdot w)$. Letting $w=1_V$ and using that $g:V\to V$ is surjective, we see that $g(1_V) = 1_V$. In particular: $\mathbb{C} 1_V$ is a subrepresentation of $V$ isomorphic to the trivial representation. If $V$ is irreducible, this forces $V$ itself to be the trivial representation.